# JS fullcalendar, TypeError when parsing PHP Variable to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar, typeerror

I´m having trouble using `FullCalendar v3.8.2` and the eventDataTransform Method.
I´m searching for hours now, so to prevent going crazy I write my first StackOverflow post...

I want pass an additonal parameter to the event Object, calles `blockd`. So in frontent the events which are blocked get a different styling

If I pass the `blocked` parameter with `Int 1`, the events of the calendar show up in the frontend. ( As shown in code ex below )

Though I do a PHP variable `e.g. $is_blocked` instead, I get a `TypeError` in frontend and the events dont show up.

Thats my `fullcalendar.js` script:

```
eventSources: [
            {
              url: WP_PUBLIC_DATA.pluginsUrl + '/dev-booking-system/dbs-calendar-feed.php', // use the `url` property
              className: 'dbs-event',
              eventDataTransform: function( eventData ){
                var blocked = parseInt( eventData.blocked );
                if( blocked == 1 ){
                    var substr = 'Reserviert - ' + eventData.title.substring( 0, 15 ) + '...';
                    return {
                        id: eventData.id,
                        title: substr,
                        start: eventData.start,
                        end: eventData.end,
                        className: 'dbs-event--disabled-by-load'
                    };
                }
              }
            }
        ],
```

When sending a JSON to javascript file, something weird happens.
eventSoruces url gets data from php file with a wordpress loop.

That's the point where it gets weird. Passing `'blocked' => 1` works, passing `'blocked' => $is_blocked` dont work (value is converted to int via intval)

```
if( $event_listing->have_posts() ) :
        while( $event_listing->have_posts() ) : $event_listing->the_post();

            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $title = get_the_title();

            $is_blocked = intval( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'event_reserved', true ) );
            $start = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'start_trip', true ) != '' ? get_post_meta( $post_id, 'start_trip', true ) : NULL;
            $end = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'end_trip', true ) != '' ? get_post_meta( $post_id, 'end_trip', true ) : NULL;


            $event_array[] = array(
                'id' => $post_id,
                'title' => $title,
                'start' => $start,
                'end' => $end,
                // 'blocked' => 1,
                'blocked' => $is_blocked,
                'allDay' => true // Event ist nicht Zeitabhängig
            );

        endwhile;
    else:
        wp_send_json_error( "No events found" );
    endif; 

echo json_encode($event_array);

exit;
```

Using Wordpress, i enqueue the scripts in correct order:

```
//fullcalendar
wp_enqueue_script('dbs-fullcalendar-moment-scripts',  plugins_url('assets/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '3.8.2', true );
wp_enqueue_script('dbs-fullcalendar-scripts',  plugins_url('assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js', __FILE__ ) , array('jquery'), '3.8.2', true );
```

Firefox says `TypeError: eventInput is undefined`, Chrome against says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined`

Do you have any idea whats going on ?
Would be great hearing from your, stop me for drinking too much coffee ;)

Here is the JSON Result:

```
0:
    id: 3453
    title:  "19. März bis 23. März Beipieltext"
    start:  "2018-03-19"
    end:    "2018-03-23"
    blocked:    0
    allDay: true
1:
    id: 3451
    title:  "09. März bis 11. März Beispieltext"
    start:  "2018-03-09"
    end:    "2018-03-11"
    blocked:    1
    allDay: true
```

The 'blocked' value recieved as an int value, but it seems javascript has a problem with the '0', because transfering only '1' values as explained above, the whole thing works

Comment: Can you please show the JSON which is the result of `json_encode($event_array)`? That's likely to be the key to the problem. It seems that the Javascript does not like the data it has been given. You can look in your browser's network tools when the ajax request is made, find the request to dbs-calendar-feed.php and look in the Response tab to find the output, then post it in your question. thanks.

Comment: json result added to question above ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that whenever `blocked` is 0, your eventDataTransform method does not return anything to the calendar, so the code which tries to use the returned event is crashing because it's trying to access an event object which doesn't exist.

Even if you're not going to change the event data, you still need to just return the existing event data back again.

You also don't need to do parseInt() since `blocked` is already a number, and you don't really need to build a new event object - you can just modify the one given to you. So your code can be as follows:

```
eventDataTransform: function( eventData ){
  if( eventData.blocked == 1 ){
    var substr = 'Reserviert - ' + eventData.title.substring( 0, 15 ) + '...';
    eventData.title = substr;
    eventData.className = 'dbs-event--disabled-by-load';
  }

  return eventData; //always return something, even if it wasn't modified
}
```

Comment: Wow, thats great! worked instantly. Had to remember that a function alwas have to return a value. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If the answer helped you please remember to mark it as accepted (click on the tick icon next to the question so it turns green) - thanks :-)

Comment: P.S. you said "a function always have to return a value". Not strictly true. **This** function always needs to return a value (and that's documented at (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform) but it's not always the case for every function, it depends on the circumstances and the purpose of the function.

Comment: You´re welcome. Yes, indeed there are functions / methods e.g. in Java which not returning values (void). Thanks ;)